# How can I configure BOINC to start at startup?

Tags: system-tray, boinc

I can't get BOINC to start with the rest of the startup applications and the software itself doesn't have that option, I've been reading about it on Berkeley's forum but I can't get the answer, it appears the 12.04 version has a lot of errors that the previous version didn't. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: First, how did you install the Boinc software? Via Software Center or downloading from Berkley?

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing, but then yesterday used System Monitor, and there is a Process running (Einstein@Home IIRC, grinding away at some data), so the BOINC Manager doesn't have to be obviously running for BOINC to be happening.

Check that, you might be just fine!

Answer (score 0):

try with bum , a good startup manager .open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install bum & sudo bum
```

by selecting you can manage your startup services ,:D

hope that helps

Comment: If he installed Boinc directly via Berkley, `bum` will not help him, since the Berkley installer does not install the startup scripts in the `init.d` dir. You need to install it manually, and *then* use `bum` to enable/disable it, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just enable service. Example for Ubuntu:

```
sudo systemctl enable boinc-client
```

If this not working, open config - /etc/default/boinc-client you'll see startup script path:

```
/etc/init.d/boinc-client
```

check out if this file exists and value of ENABLED variable (should be "1" in both files).

To start service manually:

```
/etc/init.d/boinc-client start
```

Also you can add boinc client binary (e.g. /usr/bin/boinc) to startup applications. Path depends of you distro, can be found in files mentioned above.